# ShellExecute raises type mismatch error when trying to open a file

Tags: vbscript, shellexecute

I am trying to automate a .application file to open automatically on an end users machine. The code I found online says to do this:

```
Dim my_file

my_file = "c:/location/example.application"

ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, my_file, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
```

but when I try to run it I get a type mismatch error on line 4 which is the `ShellExecute` line. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`ShellExecute()` is a method of a Shell Application object. You'll need to create an instance of the class before you can call one of its methods:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute my_file
```

Most of the parameters to `ShellExecute()` are optional and can be omitted, if you'd like.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page for information.

Also note that constants defined by external type libraries (as is the case here) are not immediately available to VBScript. That means your script will not understand `vbNormalFocus`. The easiest way to overcome this is to just define the constants yourself.

```
Const vbNormalFocus = 1
```